# How to change a class' properties after addClass()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, class

I have a form that sends an email. I send the data to AJAX and then to a php file. When the data successfully sends, I have a success function in my ajax. If the data sent successfully, I am wanting the form to `display: none;` (which I have accomplished) and for a new class to appear. I know that can be done with the addClass() method. However, I do not understand how I can accomplish this. The reason being is I created a simple `div` with a success message, so upon page load I am hiding that div. So, my thoughts were to remove the class of `email-success` because I have it set to `display: none;` and then to add the class of its child div `email-success-container`. This is not working.

Does anyone know how I can accomplish this?

```
<div class="white-green">
  <!-- The success div when the email is successfully sent .. I want this to show after email sends-->
  <div class="email-success">
    <div class="email-success-container">
      <div id="email-success-title">THANK YOU FOR CONTACTING OUR AGENCY!</div>
      <div id="email-success-description">Your submission has been received and one of our team members will contact you shortly.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="project-container">
        <div class="project-input-container">
  <!-- Form for email.... it shows on page load-->
  <form action="" autocomplete="on" method="POST" id="project-information-form">
    <input type="text" class="input-borderless" id="project-name" placeholder="Your Name">
    <input type="text" class="input-borderless" id="title-roll" placeholder="Title/Role">
    <input type="email" class="input-borderless" id="project-email" placeholder="Email Address">
    <input type="text" class="input-borderless" id="project-number" placeholder="Phone Number">
    <input type="text" class="input-borderless" id="project-company" placeholder="Company/URL">
</div>
<div class="project-input-container2">
  <textarea rows="3" class="input-borderless" id="project-description" placeholder="Describe the project"></textarea>
  <input type="text" class="input-borderless" id="project-source" placeholder="How did you hear about us?">
  <input type="text" class="input-borderless" id="project-socialMedia" placeholder="Which of our social media influenced you the most?">
  <input type="text" class="input-borderless" id="project-humanTest" placeholder="Human Test: What day comess after Thursday?">
</div>
<input type="submit" id="submit-project" value="Send Project Inquiry">
</form>
</div>
```

My ajax success:

```
success: function (data) {
    //console.log(data); // data object will return the response when status code is 200
    if (data == "Error!") {
        alert("Unable to send email!");
        alert(data);
    } else {
        $(".project-container").addClass("removeClass");
        $(".white-green").addClass("email-success-container");
        $(".white-green").removeClass("email-success");
        $(".announcement_success").fadeIn();
        $(".announcement_success").show();
        $('.announcement_success').html('Email Successfully sent!');
        $('.announcement_success').delay(5000).fadeOut(400);
    }
},
```

CSS for the div I am trying to get to show after the email sends:

```
.removeClass {
    display: none;
}
.email-success {
    display: none;
}
.email-success-container {
    margin-left: 9%;
    margin-top: 250px;
}
#email-success-title {
    color: #ba5a45;
    font-size: 3em;
}
#email-success-description {
    color: #ba5a45;
    font-size: 2em;
}
```

Does anyone know what I can do to accomplish this?

Comment: Where is `class=project-container` in the HTML?

Comment: For what you're doing, it sounds like just calling `.hide()` and `.show()` would be simpler than playing with classes.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include that. I updated my question. How could I include that within my `success:`? Wouldn't I only need to do a `.show()` because I am doing `display: none` on page load?

Comment: You use `.show()` when you send the AJAX request, and `.hide()` in the success function.

Comment: @Barmar I am confused on what you mean. I have the main form that displays on page load. I keep the `emaill-success` div at `display: none;` so it doesn't show on page load, unless there is another way. Then when the success goes through, I add the class to my form to not display it. How can I just `.show()` my `email-success` div when I have it set to `display: none;`?

Comment: If it's not displayed at page load, why do you have to do something in the success function to not display it? I assumed you had done something before the AJAX request to display it, and then the success function needs to undo that to make it invisible again.

Comment: `$(".email-success").show()` will show it.

Comment: `.hide()` and `.show()` use inline styles on the elements, so they take precedence over CSS.

Comment: Awesome. That did it for me. I didn't think that was the case and I thought it would have just done `display: none;` again. Thanks! Feel free to write the answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the `display: none;` CSS using `.show()` and `.hide()`.

```
$(".email-success").show();
```

This uses inline style attributes, which takes precedence over stylesheets.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `$(".classname").css("property","value");` for example: `$(".email-success").css("display","block");`

It's more general solution since with this you can change any property u want, not just display

Comment: So, I can use this in my `success:` and change the properties of classes within it?